# how to change add to cart button after adding product to the cart using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i have no idea how to do that ,
after user add a particular product to the cart i want to change the add to cart button my cart work on sessions

```
  <?php require'admin/dist/db.php';
  $sql = " SELECT * FROM products";
  $res = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id=$row['id'];
  $_SESSION['product_id']=$id;?>
  <div class="cards ">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="colorProd"></div>
      <div class="imgProd" style="background-image: url(img/product/<?echo $row['img_path'];?>);"></div>
      <div class="infoProd">
        <p class="nombreProd"><?echo $row['product_name'];?></p>
        <p class="extraInfo"></p>
        <div class="actions">
          <div class="preciosGrupo">
            <p class="precio precioOferta">9,999</p>
            <p class="precio precioProd"><?echo $row['product_price'];?>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="icono action aFavs" title="Add TO Wishlist">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
              <path d="M47 5c-6.5 0-12.9 4.2-15 10-2.1-5.8-8.5-10-15-10A15 15 0 0 0 2 20c0 13 11 26 30 39 19-13 30-26 30-39A15 15 0 0 0 47 5z">
              </path>
            </svg>
          </div>
           <form action="" method="post">
          <label >
            <button  class="  pointer addtocart " id="<? echo $row['id'];?>" type="submit" >
            </button>
            <div class="icono action alCarrito">
              <!-- alCarrito -->
              <svg class="inCart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
                <title>Added To Cart !</title>
              <path d="M30 22H12M2 6h6l10 40h32l3.2-9.7"></path>
              <circle cx="20" cy="54" r="4"></circle>
              <circle cx="46" cy="54" r="4"></circle>
              <circle cx="46" cy="22" r="16"></circle>
            <path d="M53 18l-8 9-5-5"></path>
          </svg>
          <svg class="outCart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <title>Add To Cart</title>
          <path d="M2 6h10l10 40h32l8-24H16"></path>
          <circle cx="23" cy="54" r="4"></circle>
          <circle cx="49" cy="54" r="4"></circle>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?echo $row['id'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?echo $row['product_name'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?echo $row['product_price'];?>">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<? }}?>
</div>
<?if(isset($_POST['id']))
{$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$cart  = array('id' => $id,'name' => $name,'price' => $price);
$_SESSION['cart'][$id]= $cart;
}?>
```

**what i want to do is just tell to php tht the already added product's cart button changes**
[this 3 cards output from my data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsFQ.png) 
and after user add a product to cart i wana display the add to cart button something like this
[see the cart svg i wana change it like this after a product added to cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsFQ.png)

i have this class for css **enCarrito** if i add this class in  `<div class="cards enCarrito">`
then the cart svg changed like i uploaded in 2nd image

THANKS !

Comment: Both your links point to the same image.
This makes understanding what you are trying to achieve more difficult.

Comment: look the shopping cart svg next to the prices it looks different on both images

Comment: Are you sure? My eyes may not be what they used to be, but 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsFQ.png' and 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsFQ.png' look mighty identical to me as far as links go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on a lot of conjecture and assumes that the page reloads after you added something to the cart.

I am assuming, that you will be storing your cart in the session, as in:
`$_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['id']`.

Now, whilst (re-)building the page, you can use the `in_array` function to determine, whether the item currently being built already is in the cart.

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id=$row['id'];
  $inCart = (in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart']) ? 'enCarrito' : '';
?>
  <div class="cards <?= $inCart ?>">
```

Assuming you wish to do this with JQuery, you should give your div a proper id as in `<div id='product_<?= $id ?>'>` and then add the class with  `$('#product' + ID).addClass('enCarrito');` as documented at https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: in_array function does this job but, after the session created i need to refresh the page , because on 1st attempt it only creates session and not going to run the in_array function if i refresh the page then the code work as i want !

Comment: If you want to do this without a page refresh, please look at the lower part of my answer, @lucifer, where I left a tiny JQuery snippet for you.